# I have an unordered list with no bulletpoints, animated to dissapear off screen. However, the last three letters don't move

Tags: html, css, animation

I've been following a tutorial, but they haven't been explaining anything. I'm also new to this site, so if I misformat anything please tell me so I can learn and reformat to fix it.

The code was originally used with the word "Mercy" on the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=monnVA94Iiw). The same amount of letters as in mercy are the only ones working now, if that helps.

What I have for the HTML as a whole:https://pastebin.com/8MHzd3SD

The CSS used to control it: https://pastebin.com/ab5Ff4ev

```css
@font-face {font-family: Lato; src: url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&subset=latin,latin-ext);}

body{
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #696969;
  align-items: center;
  height:100vh;
}

.box{
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  padding:100px;
  margin: auto;
}

.box li{
  list-style-type: none;
  transition: all 2s;
  letter-spacing:12px;
  font-size:120px;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.box:hover li{
  transform: rotate(55deg) translateY(-300px);
  opacity:0;
  filter: blur(30px);
}

.box:hover::after {
  transform: scale(0.8);
  transition-delay: 2.4s;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
li:nth-child(1){
  transition-delay: 0;
}
li:nth-child(2){
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
li:nth-child(3){
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
li:nth-child(4){
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
li:nth-child(5){
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}
li:nth-child(6){
  transition-delay: 0.5;
}
li:nth-child(7){
  transition-delay: 0.6;
}
li:nth-child(8){
  transition-delay: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

    <ul class="box">
      <li>P</li>
      <li>R</li>
      <li>O</li>
      <li>J</li>
      <li>E</li>
      <li>C</li>
      <li>T</li>
      <li>S</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't add seconds to your last three `li:nth-child` CSS

```
li:nth-child(1){
  transition-delay: 0;
}
li:nth-child(2){
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
li:nth-child(3){
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
li:nth-child(4){
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
li:nth-child(5){
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}
li:nth-child(6){
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}
li:nth-child(7){
  transition-delay: 0.6s;
}
li:nth-child(8){
  transition-delay: 0.7s;
}
```